# fixest::etable()を使ってクロスリファレンスをする方法はありますか？

Tags: r, markdown

[英語版でも同様の質問](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70476985) を投稿しています。

## 質問

`fixest::etable()` を使ってクロスリファレンスをする方法はありますか？`etable` は，簡易的なメソッドですが，とても便利です．もしできる方法があるととても助かります．

環境は，Windows 10で，R 4.1.2を使っています．RStudioで`bookdown::render_book()`をしています．ファイル構成と内容は以下です．

- index.Rmd
- _bookdown.yml
- _output.yml

## ソースコード

index.Rmd

````
---
title: "test"
author: "null"
output: pdf_document
fontfamily: lmodern
documentclass: bxjsarticle
classoption: |
  xelatex,
  ja=standard,
  a4
link-citations: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
    echo = FALSE,
    warning = FALSE,
    message = FALSE,
    dev = "cairo_pdf",
    results = "asis"
)
```

```{r model}
library(fixest)
model <- feols(dist ~ speed, cars)
```

```{r etable}
etable(model, title = "etable", tex = TRUE)
```

\@ref(tab:etable)
````

_bookdown.yml

```yml
delete_merged_file: true
```

_output.yml

```yml
bookdown::pdf_document2:
    latex_engine: xelatex
    dev: cairo_pdf
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: true
```

## 出力結果

図のように，クロスリファレンスの部分は「??」と表示されます．現状は，自分で番号を振るしかありません．

[image: 出力結果]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**更新**: なぜ見落としたのか自分でも全く分かりませんが, チャンクラベルではなく `label` 引数でラベルを指定することができます.

**fixest** パッケージはあまり使ったことがありませんが, <s>ヘルプを見る限りその関数には相互参照を操作する機能はないようです. しかし, 以下のようにタイトルに無理やりLaTeXコマンドを挿入すればできそうです.</s> 以下のように `label` 引数に指定します. 接頭辞の `tab:` も書く必要があります.

````
```{r etable}
etable(model, title = "etable", tex = TRUE, label = "tab:etable")
```
````

少し蛇足かもしれませんが, いくつか補足しておきます:

- 一般的にはチャンクラベルだけでは表の相互参照はできません. グラフに対する相互参照だけです. (RMarkdownの後継として開発中のQuartoではできるようになるようです) officedown など一部のパッケージで, 表の相互参照にも対応しています.
- 回帰分析の結果を自動で LaTeX の表にして, かつ相互参照もしたい場合, stargazer パッケージを使うという手もあります. ただしこちらも, 相互参照の使用にはひと工夫が必要になることがあります. (詳細は https://gedevan-aleksizde.github.io/rmdja/advanced-tabulate.html を見てください)

Comment: 回答してくださってありがとうございます．再現できました．

Comment: 普通に `label` 引数で指定できたので修正しました. ドキュメントも確認し実際に動かしてもみたのですが, 自分でもなぜ見落としたのかわかりません.